# Is there a Shorter way - SQL - multiple LIKE and OR

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Is there away to shorten a SQL statement like this? If so what would it be in MySQL and also in PostgreSQL?

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station 
WHERE (city LIKE 'A%' OR city LIKE 'E%' OR 
       city LIKE 'I%' OR city LIKE 'O%' OR city LIKE 'U%')
AND (city LIKE '%a' OR city LIKE '%e' OR city LIKE '%i' OR 
     city LIKE '%o' OR city LIKE '%u');
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL? They're not the same thing and have different syntax. Please [edit] your post to remove the one that does not apply to your post. Tags have meaning and relevance here; please use only those that actually apply to your question - don't just randomly choose things that sound familiar or similar. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion ...

Comment: I am looking for a solution for both MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With MySQL, we could use a regular expression, something like this:

```
WHERE city REGEXP '^[AEIOU].*[aeiou]$'
```

---

Not to dive too deep into regular expressions, but as an aid to deciphering that:

- the caret `^` matches the beginning of the string
- the next character has to be one of the characters in the set in the square brackets  `A`, `E`, `I`, `O` or `U`
- followed by any number of any character, the dot `.` matches any character, the `*` is repetition, zero, one or more
- the last character has to match one of characters in the square brackets `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u` because the dollar sign `$` matches the end of the string

---

For testing, use a SELECT statement

```
 SELECT t.city
      , t.city REGEXP '^[AEIOU].*[aeiou]$'
   FROM ( SELECT 'A' AS city 
          UNION ALL SELECT 'Aa' 
          UNION ALL SELECT 'Abba' 
          UNION ALL SELECT 'a' 
        ) t
```

---

As Gordon points out in a comment, the same approach using a regular expression comparison will work in PostgreSQL. But there syntax is a a little different, the comparison operation is a tilde `~` character, in place of MySQL `REGEXP` or `RLIKE` keyword.

```
WHERE city      ~ '^[AEIOU].*[aeiou]$'
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: In Postgres, you would use `~` rather than `REGEXP`.

Comment: I appreciate that you did dive in. Definitely helps. Thanks

Comment: As Gordon points out, this same approach will work in Postgres, but the regular expression comparison operator is a `~` character, in place of MySQL `REGEXP` or `RLIKE` keywords.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP